# UImage view animation it doesn't work on my iPhone

Tags: ios, animation, imageview

After build code, it doesn't have any animation on my cellphone

but the code looks good, i don't know how to figure it out ,

and my image is 829 * 445, does it cause this problem ?

Could someone help me to solve this problem i will really appreciate it, thanks

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,150)];
    imageView.animationImages = animationImages ;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
    imageView.animationDuration= 4.0;
    [imageView startAnimating];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self
                                   selector:@selector(animationDone:)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
} 

-(void)animationDone:(NSTimer*)inTimer
{
    [inTimer invalidate];
    inTimer = nil;
    NSLog(@"animationDone ");

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't added imageView to your ViewController view.

Try `[self.view addSubview:imageView];` in `-viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not adding the animating `UIImageView` to your view hierarchy. Right before your `[imageView startAnimating];` line add the below line of code:

```
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use animation block code instead of the older method. The animation will tell you when its done. You don't need to set a timer.

```
NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],nil];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,150)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

        for (int loop = 0; loop < 4; loop++) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFornmat:@"%d.jpg", (loop + 1)]];
            [imageView setImage:image];
        }

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         NSLog(@"animationDone");
    }];
```